# Database Design For Tournament Management Software

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm currently designing a web application using php, javascript, and MySQL. I'm considering two options for the databases.

Having a master table for all the tournaments, with basic information stored there along with a tournament id. Then I would create divisions, brackets, matches, etc. tables with the tournament id appended to each table name. Then when accessing that tournament, I would simply do something like "SELECT * FROM BRACKETS_[insert tournamentID here]".

My other option is to just have generic brackets, divisions, matches, etc. tables with each record being linked to the appropriate tournament, (or matches to brackets, brackets to divisions etc.) by a foreign key in the appropriate column.

My concern with the first approach is that it's a bit too on the fly for me, and seems like the database could get messy very quickly. My concern with the second approach is performance. This program will hopefully have a national if not international reach, and I'm concerned with so many records in a single table, and with so many people possibly hitting it at the same time, it could cause problems.

I'm not a complete newb when it comes to database management; however, this is the first one I've done completely solo, so any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you actually need to store in these tables ? Dates of tournaments, who took part in which, who won, which player is in which team (if there are any teams), what prizes exist and what prizes were awarded etc. ? Once you have all that, it will be easier to come up with a database schema.

Comment: I'm still nailing that down, but my question is a bit more general than that. I guess I am asking, is it better to have lots of tables with less rows or less tables with more rows, or does it make a difference? Sometime tomorrow I'll post a more detailed list of what's in each table though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not create tables for each tournament.  A table is a *type* of an entity, not an *instance* of an entity.  Maintainability and scalability would be horrible if you mix up those concepts.  You even say so yourself:

> This program will hopefully have a national if not international reach, and I'm concerned with so many records in a single table, and with so many people possibly hitting it at the same time, it could cause problems.

How on Earth would you scale to that level if you need to create a whole table for each record?

Regarding the performance of your second approach, why are you concerned?  Do you have specific metrics to back up those concerns?  Relational databases tend to be *very* good at querying relational data.  So keep your data relational.  Don't try to be creative and undermine the design of the database technology you're using.

You've named a few types of entities:

- Tournament
- Division
- Bracket
- Match
- Competitor
- etc.

These sound like tables to me.  Manage your indexes based on how you query the data (that is, don't over-index or you'll pay for it with inserts/updates/deletes).  Normalize the data appropriately, de-normalize where audits and reporting are more prevalent, etc.  If you're worried about performance then keep an eye on the query execution paths for the ways in which you access the data.  Slight tweaks can make a big difference.

Don't pre-maturely optimize.  It adds complexity without any actual reason.

Comment: Note also that you can create compiled Views for things like `BRACKETS_[insert tournamentID here]` and select from those.

Comment: Thanks for the answer including the theoretical approach of actual entities versus types of entities. That reasoning is what helps me wrap my head around different concepts. So thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, find the entities that you will need to store; things like tournament, event, team, competitor, prize etc. Each of these entities will probably be tables.

It is standard practice to have a primary key for each of them. Sometimes there are columns (or group of columns) that uniquely identify a row, so you can use that as primary key. However, usually it's best just to have a column named `ID` or something similar of numeric type. It will be faster and easier for the RDBMS to create and use indexes for such columns.

Store the data where it belongs: I expect to see the date and time of an event in the `events` table, not in the `prizes` table.

Another crucial point is conforming to the [First normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), since that assures data atomicity. This is important because it will save you a lot of headache later on. By doing this correctly, you will also have the correct number of tables.

Last but not least: add relevant indexes to the columns that appear most often in queries. This will help a lot with performance. Don't worry about tables having too many rows, RDBMS-es these days handle table with hundreds of millions of rows, they're designed to be able to do that efficiently.

Comment: "hundreds of millions of rows" - Exactly.  I've heard so many developers claim that they're working with "a lot of data" and they're talking about thousands of rows, maybe tens of thousands.  On the scale of "a lot of data" thousands of rows is statistically indistinguishable from zero rows.

Comment: Agreed most developers start jumping up and down with 1 million rows saying the database is slow due to the data size. I have worked with tables reaching 1,5 billion rows or over 750GB and still had good response from the server. The key to any database is getting the design right. If you don't get it right before going into production you are not going to have a very good time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish I could accept multiple answers. But the above one is just slightly more what I was looking for as an answer. But your answer was just as good. Also thanks for confirming what I assumed about database performance but wasn't sure about, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of creating new tables whenever a new instance of an item appears is really bad, sorry.

A  (surely incomplete) list of why this is a bad idea:

- Your code will need to automatically add tables whenever a new Division or whatever is created. This is definitely a bad practice and should be limited to extremely niche cases - which yours definitely isn't.
- In case you decide to add or revise a table structure later (e.g. adding a new field) you will have to add it to *hundreds* of tables which will be cumbersome, error prone and a big maintenance headache
- A RDBMS is built to scale in terms of rows, not tables and associated (indexes, triggers, constraints) elements - so you are working *against* your tool and not with it.
- THIS ONE SHOULD BE THE REAL CLINCHER - how do you plan to handle requests like "list all matches which were played on a Sunday" or "find the most recent three brackets where Frank Perry was active"?

You say:

*I'm not a complete newb when it comes to database management; however, this is the first one I've done completely solo...*

Can you remember another project where tables were cloned whenever a new set was required? If yes, didn't you notice some problems with that approach? If not, have you considered that this is precisely what a DBA would never ever do for any reason whatsoever?

Comment: Most projects I worked on involved creating entire new db's for each client resulting in cloned tables for everyone we serviced. I did notice some problems and that's why I came here to ask for opinions. I'm still learning how to do this myself so I don't see all the reasons to do one or the other quite yet. Thanks for your insight and help.

Comment: Please keep in mind my fourth point: having data spread out on separate tables makes most for of reporting/aggregation practically impossible. This is #1 reason to drop the idea immediately. Even if such report was not a requirement for version 1.0 you would completely negate any chance to create one later.

Comment: The scenario you mention (cloning tables for new clients) makes sense so that you completely segregate different customers, and can for example backup only one customer dataset and so on. Please understand that in this case none of these reasons apply and your design would create lots of limitations.

Comment: I do understand that, and I'm going with the second approach for your reasons and the many ones listed above. I wasn't set on one or the other because I didn't know which one was better. That's why I asked the question. Now that I have all this info I'll make the right decision, and take the second approach.

Answer (score 1):

Beside compromising the quality and maintainability of your code (as others have pointed out), it's questionable whether you'd actually gain any performance either.

When you execute...

```
SELECT * FROM BRACKETS_XXX
```

...the DBMS needs to find the table whose name matches "BRACKETS_XXX" and that search is done in the DBMS'es data dictionary which itself is a bunch of tables. So, you are replacing a search within your tables with a search within data dictionary tables. You pay the price of the search either way.

*(The dictionary tables may or may not be "real" tables, and may or may not have similar performance characteristics as real tables, but I bet these performance characteristics are unlikely to be better than "normal" tables for **large** numbers of rows. Also, performance of data dictionary is unlikely to be documented and you really shouldn't rely on undocumented features.)*

Also, the DBMS would suddenly need to [prepare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepare_%28SQL%29) many more SQL statements (since they are now *different* statements, referring to separate tables), which would present the additional pressure on performance.